# Keyboard shortcuts for separating the zoom-in/out of x and y axes in a chart

Tags: info-visualisation, zooming

Currently, I am working on a plotting library to plot a few charts.
Most of the charts data vary in the x-dimension much more than in the y-dimension.
Example:

```
time x y
0    0  0
1    1  0.0044
2    2  0.0085
```

Currently, we use Ctrl + Wheel to zoom-in/out. It's good if the values on both axes vary with the same degree, but this is not the case.

I have been thinking about separating the zooming behavior, examples for schemes:

#### scheme 1

Ctrl + Wheel: both axes.
Ctrl + Shift + Wheel: x-axis.
Ctrl + Alt + Wheel: y-axis.

#### scheme 2

Mouse middle button: Switch between axis.
Ctrl + Wheel: zoom the current selected axis or both.

---

I have been thinking about the schemes, but I don't think it's too intuitive.

I have to depend on being intuitive for the user interface, as the program itself is very complex with a huge user guide. And I don't want to add non-necessary documentation for simple navigation.

So are there more intuitive shortcuts for special modes in zooming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is like this:

`Wheel` for Y Axis,
`Wheel + CTRL` for X Axis

You could add `Shift + CTRL + Wheel` for both, even though a simultan scrolling/zooming is pretty uncommon as it is more effective to scroll in one way for more preciseness.

This is a pretty common pattern for navigating a 2d layer, as seen in Adobe products & Affinity products. If you aim for zooming, add a magnifying tool and offer the same UX pattern to the zoom function.